# Why does an IPv6 neighbour router status become STALE? How can I avoid it?

Tags: ipv6, iproute, arp

I have a VM on a host with bridged networking (hence, with its own MAC address).  Both host and VM run CentOS.  Their network is managed by simple `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enpXsY` files. IPv4 works just fine.

I have assigned an IPv6 address to the VM (the host also has one) which is routed correctly in the data centre.  Most connections use IPv4, however (no DNS AAAA entry for the machine yet, still testing IPv6).

When I boot up the VM it has full IPv6 connectivity.  However, **after a while IPv6 connectivity stops working** (IPv6 magic?).  I have narrowed to problem down to neighbour (ARP/NDISC cache) data:

Not working, cannot ping or connect by IPv6 in or out:

```
# ip -6 neighbour 
fe80::1 dev enp1s2 lladdr 0c:86:72:2e:04:28 router STALE
```

Fix/workaround to refresh the cache:

```
# ip -6 neighbour flush dev enp1s2
# ip -6 neighbour
(empty, as expected)
```

Then `ping6` the host from within the VM to fill the cache:

```
# ping6 2912:1375:23:9a6c::2
PING 2912:1375:23:9a6c::2(2912:1375:23:9a6c::2) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2912:1375:23:9a6c::2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.35 ms
64 bytes from 2912:1375:23:9a6c::2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.468 ms
^C
# ip -6 neighbour
fe80::1 dev enp1s2 lladdr 0c:86:72:2e:04:28 router REACHABLE
2912:1375:23:9a6c::2 dev enp1s2 lladdr 08:21:4b:b7:f8:31 DELAY
```

IPv6 neighbour/ARP table restored to validity and connectivity is working in and out!

**So my questions are:**

1. Why does the cache become stale?
2. What can I do to avoid it?

Of course I could run those commands in a `cron` job (how often?) but I suppose that cannot really be needed for IPv6 to work in general?

PS: I used a script for tests: **The IPv6 stack breaks down about every 20 minutes**. Can that be explained by RFCs?

Comment: "Stale" means "previously detected neighbor no longer reachable". I don't think the problem's in the IPv6 stack, it's more likely to be in the configuration. You're doing connectivity testing in a Data Center - I'd close this question and ask in [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) instead, them guys have a goodly amount of experience of these environments.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Thanks, will do that.

Comment: You's most welcome :-)

Comment: STALE means the entry is not up to date (it's a normal transition from REACHABLE). It might still work or not work. Not to be confused with INCOMPLETE or FAILED. Excerpt from man ip neighbour "stale  the neighbour entry is valid but suspicious." "incomplete the neighbour entry has not (yet) been validated/resolved." "failed max number of probes exceeded without success, neighbor validation has ultimately failed.". Usually sending (again) traffic to a stale destination still sends traffic but also lazily initiates a NDP NS to revalidate the entry.

Comment: If you firewall ICMPv6 expect connectivity problems. 20 minutes could be tied to the Router Advertisement information. Please ensure ICMPv6 is not firewalled and try again.

Comment: @A.B Thanks, I will check that again, though I am sure ICMPv6 is ACCEPTed. Is there a good way to refresh the data client side, perhaps by a connection to the router?